# Python. Импортированный файл не видит другие модули

Tags: python, файловая-система, python-import

Хочу разделить проект на несколько файлов. (структура проекта на картинке)

[image: Папка проекта]

Мне необходимо добавить файлы, обведенные в рамку (`Work_with_models.py`, `Work_with_weights.py`, `Work_with_distances.py`), в main.py. для использования функций в этих файлах.
Эти файлы используют другие библиотеки и модули.

Все необходмые для работы модули и библиотеки добавлены в main.py. В файлах, которые я импортирую, есть **только мои функции и ничего больше**.

Одна из первых импортированных библиотек в `main.py` - `os`
Файлы с функциями импортированы после всех остальных библиотек. Функции импортирую так:

```
"Другие необходимые библиотеки"
...
from Work_with_models import *
from Work_with_weights import *
from Work_with_distances import *
```

При запуске `main.py` возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: ошибка при запуске main.py]

```
C:\Programming\Miniconda3\envs\CNN\python.exe C:/Users/MRS/PycharmProjects/CNN/main.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/MRS/PycharmProjects/CNN/main.py", line 78, in <module>
        CreateDistancesGIF(DMPath)
      File "C:\Users\MRS\PycharmProjects\CNN\Work_with_distances.py", line 38, in CreateDistancesGIF
        for img in os.listdir(DMpath):
    NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Ошибка происходит при вызове функции `CreateDistancesGIF`.
Код функции:

```
def CreateDistancesGIF(DMpath):
    images = []
    for img in os.listdir(DMpath):
        im = Image.open(DMpath + '\\' + img)
        images.append(im)
    images[0].save('Distances_Matrix_GIF.gif', save_all=True, append_images=images[1:], optimize=False, duration=1000,
                   loop=0)
```

**Из-за чего возникает данная ошибка и как ее решить?**

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Если честно, не особо знаю как работают свои импорты в импортированных файлах, но попробуй просто отдельно в функции сделать импорт, если библиотека уже импортирована это не займет ни времени ни памяти

Comment: В модуле `Work_with_distances` отсутствует библиотека 'os', импортируйте её. А вот в `main` её можно не имортировать, если импортируете всё (*) или если не используете